# how to get graphical class hierarchy if we are having texture class hierarchy with doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I used the multiple inheritance in C++ classes and for documentation I used doxyWizard.In doxygen, I am getting only texture class hierarchy for my project. I have  set

```
GraphViz Package=true
Graphical_Hierarchy=YES
Class_Graph=YES
Include_Graph=YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH=YES
```

But I did not get Graphical Class Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.I have wrongly installed graphViz.After successfully installing graphviz3.0 .After installing I checked by converting .dot file into .png file in cmd.I used the command

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz3.0\html\dot.exe" -Tpng d:\abc.dot -O d:\abc.png

It was running.Than I cleared the output directory and it was giving graphical class hierarchy.